# Sorting index of array based on another array of Object in javascript/Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

i have 2 array of objects and I need to sort one array of object depends on another array key value

```
        array1: [
            {
                group: 'GROUP1',
                sort_order: 1,
            },
            {
                group: 'GROUP2',
                sort_order: 2,
            },
            {
                group: 'GROUP3',
                sort_order: 3,
            }
        ],
        array2: {
            'GROUP3' : [
                {
                    "price": 10,
                    "amount": 2,
                },
                {
                    "price": 45,
                    "amount": 7,
                },
            ],
            'GROUP2' : [
                {
                    "price": 10,
                    "amount": 2,
                },
                {
                    "price": 45,
                    "amount": 7,
                },
            ],
            'GROUP1' : [
                {
                    "price": 10,
                    "amount": 2,
                },
                {
                    "price": 45,
                    "amount": 7,
                },
            ]
        }
```

No I need to order my array2 indexes based on array1 "sort_order".

i am expecting the order of array2 something like GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't  array2 is an Object? And, Object doesn't need to be sorted. I think should change that to array.

Comment: Array2 is an object and its sequence doesn't matter.

Comment: If array2 is an array then just call Array.sort() method, and make array1 a map

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat I am showing that object in my view & I need it to be sorted, but cannot find any way

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat: You need to understand that object doesn't get sort as they are key-value pair. So, you need to make array2 an array first and then sort it.

Comment: _“Thanks in advance”_ - please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to make an attempt yourself at least, and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sorted = Object.entries(array2).sort(([groupA], [groupB]) => 
    array1.find(e => e.group === groupA).sort_order - 
    array1.find(e => e.group === groupB).sort_order)
```

would give you

```
[
    [
        "GROUP1",
        [
            {
                "price": 10,
                "amount": 2
            },
            {
                "price": 45,
                "amount": 7
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "GROUP2",
        [
            {
                "price": 10,
                "amount": 2
            },
            {
                "price": 45,
                "amount": 7
            }
        ]
    ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you need to sort second array using info from first one. I prefer to keep original array and do sort in computed property.
Example:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: () => ({
    array1: [
      {
        group: 'GROUP1',
        sort_order: 1,
      },
      {
        group: 'GROUP2',
        sort_order: 2,
      },
      {
        group: 'GROUP3',
        sort_order: 3,
      },
    ],
    array2: {
      'GROUP3' : [
        {
          "price": 10,
          "amount": 2,
        },
        {
          "price": 45,
          "amount": 7,
        },
      ],
      'GROUP2' : [
        {
          "price": 10,
          "amount": 2,
        },
        {
          "price": 45,
          "amount": 7,
        },
      ],
      'GROUP1' : [
        {
          "price": 10,
          "amount": 2,
        },
        {
          "price": 45,
          "amount": 7,
        },
      ],
    },
  }),
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.sortedArray2);
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed: {
    sortedArray2() {
      const arr2 = { ...this.array2 };
 
      this.array1.map(item1 => {
        arr2[item1.group] = arr2[item1.group].sort((a, b) => {
          switch(item1.sort_order) {
            case 1: {
              return a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1;
            }
            case 2: {
              return a.price < b.price ? 1 : -1;
            }
            default: {
              return a.amount < b.amount ? 1 : -1;
            }
          }
        });
      });
      
      return arr2;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```